# How can I covert a Jenkins log file artifact into a xml file to Publish Junit report?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, junit

Hi I am trying to get a JUnit report but currently, it fails because of error in reading the xml file:

```
url=http://jenkins-ci:8080/job/test-job/lastSuccessfulBuild
wget -q -O- $url/api/xml?tree=artifacts[relativePath] | xpath '//relativePath/text()' 2>&1 | sed -re 's/-- NODE --//g' | tail -n+3\
| while read fileName;\
do \
   wget "${url}/artifact/${fileName}";\

done
mv unit-test.log unit-test.xml
touch *.xml
```

This is what I see when I try to visulaize this with analyzer plugin:

```
unit-test.xml : The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. Nested exception: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

Would love if somebody can propose a solution in groovy

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my need for JUnit report history/visualization via the [JUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin).

The configuration is very simple and straight-forward:

> Specify the path to JUnit XML files in the Ant glob syntax, such as **/build/test-reports/*.xml. Be sure not to include any non-report files into this pattern. You can specify multiple patterns of files separated by commas. The base directory of the fileset is the workspace root.

Comment: Hi, But the issue is how do I convert this log file into XML file?

Comment: Would be hard to say without seeing the actual log file. You would most likely need to implement some sort of parser to convert the logfile into valid XML.